# How to find the queries that is blocking another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, partitioning

I am trying to drop an empty table
`drop table temp;` the query is running forever.

So, I tried to find other queries that could block the current query.
Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT *
  FROM pg_locks l
  JOIN pg_class t ON l.relation = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r'
 WHERE t.relname = 'temp';
```

This query returns with zero results

```
SELECT database, gid FROM pg_prepared_xacts;
```

This does not give any result as well.

The table is a partitioned table, the partitions attached to the table has been deleted successfully already.

I am not even able to get result for `\d temp`.

What has happened?
How can I get this fixed?

This does not happen when I tried the same in local. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Which version of pg and are these physical or logical partitions?

Comment: Partitioned table have `relkind = 'p'` so it's no surprise your query returns nothing. Typically it's easier to check `pg_stat_activity` to see if a session is blocked by something.

Comment: Even when the table gives me zero result, I am still not able to drop or even get the table description :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before running `DROP TABLE`, execute

```
SELECT pg_backend_pid();
```

That will tell you the backend process ID. Then run `DROP TABLE` *in the same database session*.

Then, when `DROP TABLE` is hanging, start a new session and run

```
SELECT pg_blocking_pids(<backend PID>);
```

Then you know which sessions are blocking you, and can kill them or take less disruptive measures for getting rid of them.

Comment: WOW! thanks

The table that I was trying to drop had delete cascade on another table.

Even though my current table is empty, it is blocked by updates into the cascade table.

Comment: This is such a savior, for debugging many other scenarios too I can use this, thanks

Comment: try select pg_cancel_backend(__pid__); to kill the process after it has been identified.

Comment: Thank you, I came to know of that query through another SO question and  did exactly that.